# Running Maven Struts2 app on tomcat

Tags: java, eclipse, tomcat, struts2, m2eclipse

I created a Struts2 App using Eclipse M2 Maven plugin but there is no option to run the project on my tomcat server. I tried including the server runtime libraries in the projects build path but that doesn't work. How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you build the project, it should create an output, a war file or extracted war file. You need to deploy this on the server then only you can see the application. In eclipse I believe you can configure an server. Once you have configured a server in eclipse you can tell it to look for your project build output and deploy it.

Comment: How would I go about doing that?

Answer (score 2):

In order to run project on server in eclipse, project must be in faceted form with `Dynamic Web Module` enabled. To convert project to faceted form: right click on project -> `Properties` -> `Project Facets` -> `Convert to faceted form...` -> check `Java` and `Dynamic Web Module`.

Answer (score 0):

Right click on the project and then `Run As > Run on Server`.

If you do not see that option that means your project is not configured as Web Application.